# d3.js legend cannot share object type with chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My d3.js bubble chart uses an interval to show how data changes over time.  It works well if the legend symbols are rectangles.  If the symbols are changed to circles, the update function can be called directly.  But repeatedly calling the update function using an interval consistently throws this error with each interval cycle:

> Cannot read property 'country' of undefined

Here's the legend row code...

```
    legendRow
        // WITH rect OBJECT: NO ERROR, EVEN WITH INTERVAL
        // .append('rect')
        // .attr('width', 10)
        // .attr('height', 10)
        // WITH circle OBJECT: ERROR THROWN WITH EACH INTERVAL CYCLE
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', 10)
        .attr('cy', 5)
        .attr('r', 7)
        .attr('fill', continentColor(continent));
```

The error gets thrown when data binding...

```
    function update(data) {
      // JOIN new data with old elements.
      var circles = g.selectAll('circle').data(data, function(d) {
        return d.country;  // ERROR THROWN HERE
    });
```

[Here's a fiddle to the full code.](https://jsfiddle.net/patrick_R/1vwxfk49/18/)

Why can the update function be called directly, but not from within the interval?  What am I missing?

ANSWER:  Per comments by rioV8 and Andrew Reid below.  Changing lines 131 and 145 to use the circle class stopped the error from being thrown.

Comment: select your non-legend objects by class not by type

Comment: As rioV8 notes, you need to be more specific in your selection:  `g.selectAll('.circle')` in your update function selects the legend's circles as well as the data points, this is not intended. With a class assigned to the data points, you might end up with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kqf72h6p/).

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you rioV8 and Andrew!  Now I understand.